# Including jquery in .js file

Tags: include, libraries

I am trying to clone an object using

```
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```

as per John Resig's answer to [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) .

All the information I can find on using libraries in javascript only show how to use a library within an html file... as in:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

My code is in a .js file and i get the error that jQuery is not defined.  How do I use jQuery within my .js file?

EDIT:  I'm running this code in a server.js file on a node server.  The server.js has an event handler that gives back the index.html file upon getting the "/" url.  So the server.js file isn't included in the index.html file and therefore including jquery in the html file doesn't help me, if my understanding is correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can't include it or link to it from within your .js file. You have to include it on the HTML page (`<script src="/path/to/jquery"></script>`), before you include your .js file.

Technically you *could* just copy and paste the jquery code above the code in your .js file, but it is usually a better idea to just include it on the page to avoid conflicts.